# Is 'fer' a somewhat usual spelling of 'for', or is it perhaps restricted to cricket ('five-fer')?

Tags: british-english, suffixes, sports

> **-fer**
>
> a suffix to any number, meaning the number of wickets taken by a team or bowler. (See also fifer/five-fer)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_cricket_terms)

I assume that 'fer' means, or is derived from, 'for' with the usually following number omitted. As you would say '5 for 46' (in cricket; meaning 5 wickets for 46 runs against you; so 'five-fer' would indicate the number of wickets taken only).

Is 'fer' a somewhat usual spelling of 'for' or 'for [something]'? Or is it only used in cricket? If so, how did that come about?

Comment: A "two for the price of one" offer is sometimes referred to as a "twofer" (pronounced like tufa).

Comment: @YvonneAburrow Thank you. That leads to the question how cricketers would pronounce 'five-fer'. :)

Comment: OED has spelling *fer* listed as ME=Middle English.  It also has the current word *twofer* (with non-cricket meanings) but not *fivefer*.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks for checking. As Middle English and cricket do not seem to overlap in time, I assume that that would not explain its use.

Comment: Despite being English (and therefore supposedly obsessed by all things cricket), I'd never seen that "domain-specific" usage before. Usually it's just "eye dialect" in reported speech (supposed to indicate that the speaker is "low-spoken", even though in practice that's how we all usually pronounce it).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've seen it a lot. For many examples: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22five-fer%22

Comment: Keep these mind: All I can say is there are ***no*** written instances of [*went **five-fer** (some number of runs in cricket, baseball, etc.)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22went+five-fer%22) in Google Books, but many of the hundreds of hits for [*went **five-for***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22went+five-for%22) (hyphenated or not) are obviously for exactly that context. I wouldn't set too much store by a Wikipedia entry like that. Just a few people's oddball ideas.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why use 'went'? But also, would you be able to tell roughly how many of the 'five-for' instances were _not_ followed by a number? As opposed to 'five-fer', which seems to be specifically used when omitting the following number.

Comment: I included ***went*** in my quoted string to increase the probability of getting more contextually-relevant hits. And although I didn't look past the first page of the estimated 846 hits, I can assure you that *every single one* on that first page was obviously a "sport scoring" context. Note that GB searches match hyphens as spaces, so the *exact* orthography is irrelevant in that respect. Nevertheless, *no hits at all* for your version certainly supports my perception that it's far from "mainstream accepted usage". Just some guy on Wikipedia, essentially.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, I'm very sorry to say, I think you are wrong. A 'five-fer' is a bowler's accomplishment. The bowler didn't 'go'  'five-fer'.I think your search may result in _games_ that 'went' X for Y. Also: my original observation wasn't Wikipedia. I did encounter it in the wild first.

Comment: But in fairness, I did find one instance of [***a sixfer***](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7s0bKFTQtPwC&pg=PT152&dq=%22a+sixfer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiY9Z3W5JfdAhWhsKQKHUd4BeQQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q=%22a%20sixfer%22&f=false) in *Tuffers' Alternative Guide to the Ashes*, where he says *it sparked him to bowl even faster in the next innings when he took a sixfer*. But that's the *only* contextually relevant one out of four hits for the two-word collocation. It's not exactly a widespread usage, to say the least.

Comment: My guess (as a *Southern Englishman*) is the usage may have gained some of what little traction it might have by association with ***tit-fer-tat***. Which could apply *literally* in some closely-matched sporting contexts, but it's worth noting that the fairly well-known ***titfer*** (= ***hat***, via Cockney rhyming slang) is always spelt like that. Never ***titfor***.

Comment: It's also to some extent the standard "eye dialect" spelling, intended to emphasise that the word is actually ***for***, not the homophonous ***four*** which we might otherwise be led to expect (because of the preceding word being a *number.*)

Comment: ...also note that *semantically* the precise usage you're citing is obviously a "slangy" shortening of some hypothetical (conceptually simple, but cumbersome to verbalise) noun phrase like *a [period of play within which they took] **X** [wickets] **for** [some contextually-irrelevant number of runs, which therefore needn't be stated]*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Fer](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fer)*** is an informal version of for:

> preposition, conjunction Informal.
>
> for.

The  suffix you are referring to as in twofer or fiver appears to derive from:

origin of [twofer:](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/twofer)

> 1885–90; from the phrase two for (the price of one, a nickel, etc.), ***with final (ər) humorously taken as -er***; cf. gofer

***[-er:](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/-er)***

> a suffix used in forming nouns designating persons from the object of their occupation or labor (hatter; tiler; tinner; moonshiner), or from their place of origin or abode (Icelander; southerner; villager), or designating either persons ***or things from some special characteristic or circumstance (six-footer; three-master; teetotaler; fiver; tenner).***

Dictionary.com